# Data is not sent from view (ajax) to controller (c#)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to AJAX, and I don't understand, why my data was not sent to controller.
So, on my View I have two input forms and a button:

### HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="AddName">
<input type="text" name="AddEmail"> 
<button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type="button" name="add_btn" onclick="DbAdd()">Add</button>
```

I need after button "add_btn" clicked take data from these two inputs and send them to controller.

### JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DbAdd()
    {
        // Get some values from elements on the page:
        var $form = $(this),
            addedName = $form.find("input[name='AddName']").val(),
            addedEmail = $form.find("input[name='AddEmail']").val();

        $("#UserTable").html("<div>Please Wait...</div>");
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "Save",
            data:
                {
                    name: addedName, email: addedEmail,
                },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });
}
```

And this is my controller's method "Save" (I need to save data got from ajax to my DB):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(User userinfo)
{
    string message = "";

    using (var uc = new UserContext())
    {
        uc.UserList.Add(userinfo);
        uc.SaveChanges();
        message = "Successfully Saved!";
    }
    
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return new JsonResult { Data = message };
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = message;
        return View(userinfo);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I put a break point to my controller's method, I don't receive data from ajax, null's only. So I add an empty record to DB.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I think in the url you specify {controller}/{action}

Comment: No, it's ok to use only the name of action

Comment: @Kate21 Can you add `alert(addedName);` before `$("#UserTable").html("<div>Please Wait...</div>");` and see what the value is?

Comment: Hm, the value is 'undefined'

Comment: @Kate21 I thought so, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `$form.find("input[name='AddName']").val()` and `$form.find("input[name='AddEmail']").val()` both return null. You should use `$("input[name='AddName']").val()` and `$("input[name='AddEmail']").val()` instead. Change the definition of `DbAdd()` to below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DbAdd()
    {
        // Get some values from elements on the page:
        var addedName = $("input[name='AddName']").val(),
            addedEmail = $("input[name='AddEmail']").val();

        var user = { Name: addedName, Email: addedEmail };

        $("#UserTable").html("<div>Please Wait...</div>");
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "Save",
            data: JSON.stringify({ userinfo: user }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: may be you can tell me, what shall I do to update table on my view after adding record to DB? I tried this `$("#UserTable").fnDraw();` but not successfully

Comment: Please ask a new question, I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Done, @ekad [new question is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994404/cant-redraw-a-table-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra comma which may be causing syntax error:

```
data:
{
  name: addedName, email: addedEmail, //<------------ here
}
```

and pass data like this:

```
var userinfo = { name: addedName, email: addedEmail };
data: JSON.stringify(userinfo)
```

Also you should see : [**Posting JavaScript objects with Ajax and ASP.NET MVC**](http://www.levibotelho.com/development/posting-javascript-objects-with-ajax-and-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: You're right, it's an extra comma, I've fixed it, thank you) But this is not the solution(

Comment: I tried your updated variant, but in this case after clicking a button AJAX is not working(  Thanks for the link